# Is there a way to run command line process over a selection in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, selection

In emacs it's fairly easy to run a command line process over a region (a highlighted selection).  I'm looking for the equivalent for IntelliJ.  If one even exists. In emacs it's `M-| shell-command-on-region` but IntelliJ wouldn't have command buffer, so I'm guessing if it exists it probably has a dialog or something I have to fill out, etc.

Is there a way to run command line process over a selection in IntelliJ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Why would you want to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, there are an infinite number of reasons really.  Insert file based on a highlighted path.  Sort a number of lines using sort, awk, or cut in various ways.  Keep a file full of cool utils, highlight one, have it run the values and put the contents in another file, etc.  Just to name some of things that came to mind.